# SELECT different users from same table in single JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am currently trying to join a table (tasks) with another table (users). I need to select different rows from the users table based on values in the tasks table:

```
tasks(user1, user2, user3);

users(id, name, email);
```

Previously I have linked data using a LEFT JOIN like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks LEFT JOIN users ON tasks.user1 = users.id;
```

Thats pretty simple, so I have tried using an AND like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks LEFT JOIN users ON tasks.user1 = users.id AND tasks.user2 = users.id;
```

but that returns the users fields as NULL, which makes sense as tasks.user1 is different to tasks.user2

I am pretty stumped on how to do this now, all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to repeat the join and alias the `users` table diffeently for each joined column:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON tasks.user1 = u1.id 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON tasks.user2 = u2.id 
...
```

Comment: great, this returns the data I need. I now have a problem with the column headings overriding the data in the array that is returned (I am using PHP PDO), is there a way I can craft the query to return each user as an array inside the tasks.user* value? (I can put this into a new SO question if need be?)

Comment: @MikeOram I would post a new question - I arrived here based on the mysql / sql tags - it sounds you will need a php pdo guru. You can alias the columns viz `SELECT tasks.col1, ..., u1.id AS User1ID, u1.name as User1Name, .. u2.id as User2ID, u2.Name as User2Name...` if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

use this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tasks 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON tasks.user1 = users.id 
OR tasks.user2 = users.id;
```

Comment: +1 - this will work, provided that the context of the join (i.e. whether it was `user1` or `user2` which matched) is not required elsewhere in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as per @StuartLC comment I am going to use his answer.